# CSS creating nested div box for parent div causes overlapping

Tags: html, css

I want to create a bar to go along the top of a box on a website that I am working on.

This is the desired outcome
[image]

Here's my code, I keep getting this overlap

```css
.page {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  position: relative;
}

.section {
  border: 2px solid #FBA7FF;
  width: 85%;
  height: 30%;
  margin: 1vw;
  padding: 1vw;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
}

.section h1 {
  position: relative;
}

.section_header {
  border: 4px solid #FBA7FF;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  bottom: 95%;
}
```

```html
<div class='page'>
  <div class='section'>
    <div class="section_header"></div>
    <h1>sample text</h1>
  </div>
</div>
```

So far I've got the parent div with position: relative and the child element with position: absolute then setting top and left to 0 width to 100% and bottom to 95% to attempt the desired effect yet it creates an overlap.

I can see that 0 is within the div and doesn't take into account the border which is perhaps why this is happening.

Comment: Why are you positioning the header absolutely? - Just remove that and try using `flex-direction:column`

Comment: Causes the child element to position istelf left-centre of the parent element, using absolutely as the parent element is set to relative.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```css
 * {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    margin: 0;
}
        .page {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  position: relative;
}
.section {
    width: 100%;
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: center;
}
.section_header {
    width: 100%;
    background: #FBA7FF;
    display: block;
    height: 70px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class='page'>
        <div class='section'>
          <div class="section_header"></div>
            <h1>sample text</h1>
          </div>
      </div>
```

Comment: Adding the * box sizing  worked, could you explain why please?

Answer (score 1):

Remove the `position:absolute` and use `flex-direction:column;`

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.page {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex-direction: column;
  min-height: 100vh;
  background: lightgrey;
  position: relative;
}

.section {
  border: 2px solid #FBA7FF;
  width: 85%;
  margin: 1vh auto;
  height: 30%;
  background: lightgreen;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex: 1;
  align-items: center;
}

.section_header {
  height: 50px;
  width: 100%;
  background: orange;
}
```

```html
<div class='page'>
  <div class='section'>
    <div class="section_header"></div>
    <h1>sample text</h1>
  </div>
</div>
```